# Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined while trying to send form values to firebase

Tags: javascript, forms, undefined

i'm having this error while trying to catch values from a form:

Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined. I saw explanations involving the use of the event but this is already being used. Also to not use handlesubmit() but i get another error about expecting for an function and being called an expression.

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  const {name, value, type, checked} = e.target;
  console.log('***handleInputChange', name, value);
  const isCheckBox = type === 'checkbox';
  const data = finalFormValues[name] || {};
  if (isCheckBox) {
    data[value] = checked;
  }

  const newValue = isCheckBox ? data : value;
  setFinalFormValues({ ...finalFormValues,
    [name]: newValue
  });
  console.log('***HANDLE INPUT CHANGE', data);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  setFinalFormValues({data})
  sendUserAdress();
};
```

The submit button:

```
<ConfirmButton onClick={() => {console.log('funcionando');
     handleSubmit(); 
    sendOrder(orders, logado); 
    sendUserAdress(endereco, logado); 
    setOrders([]); 
    setUseFinalFormDialog(false); 
    setUsePizzaSize(false);}}>
    Pode mandar!
</ConfirmButton>
```

Comment: hi, the `onClick` function should pass the event in, `(e) => handleSubmit(e)`

Comment: What framework is this? You should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Yeah I'm not using a submit button, guessed that maybe this is the problem. Tomorrow I test.

Comment: React is the framework.